# Groovy Script for JIRA-actions

Tags: groovy, jira

I want to achieve the following using Adaptavist Scriptrunner in JIRA: A user comments on an issue and triggers a Scriptrunner custom script. If the issue is in the state "waiting for customer reply" and the user is a customer, trigger the workflow-transition "respond to question" and transfer the issue into the state "customer responded".

The Adaptavist Scriptrunner-Plugin uses Groovy as its language of choice for custom scripts. Unfortunately I have never worked with Groovy before and thus have no idea what I have to do to make this work. Out of the examples in the Scriptrunner docs I made the following:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor

def issue = event.issue
def workflow = ComponentAccessor.getWorkflowManager().getWorkflow(issue)
def wfd = workflow.getDescriptor()
def actionName = wfd.getAction(transientVars["actionId"] as int).getName()
```

This is supposed to get me the current workflow step but doesn't work. Would anyone be so kind, to help me write this script?

Cheers!

Comment: In what way doesn't work? How far does it get?

Comment: In the last line it says that the variable transientVars is undeclared.

Answer (score 0):

There's already available Script Listener called *Fast-track transition an issue*. You need just to create a new instance of it, bind it to your project and Issue Commented event, and add extra condition like `issue.status.name == 'Waiting For Customer Reply' && currentUser == issue.reporter`, and specify the transition. If you change workflow, you might need to update a listener too.

Also, these listeners, post-functions etc. are implemented as 'canned' scripts (classes implementing certain interface) which are available as plain groovy files in the plugin itself in the JAR file, they can teach a lot.